# How to subset a dataframe using multiple intervals into multiple subdataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(cb = c(1:10), 
                 type = c('short', 'g_long', 'g_long', 'bg_long', 'bg_long', 'bg_long','g_long','g_long', 'bg_long', 'bg_long'))

> df
   cb    type
1   1   short
2   2  g_long
3   3  g_long
4   4 bg_long
5   5 bg_long
6   6 bg_long
7   7  g_long
8   8  g_long
9   9 bg_long
10 10 bg_long
```

I want to subset dataframes whose types are all `bg_long`, so I did this:

```
bg_df <- df[df$type == 'bg_long',]

> bg_df
   cb    type
4   4 bg_long
5   5 bg_long
6   6 bg_long
9   9 bg_long
10 10 bg_long
```

However I want to get multiple dataframes, the `cb` values in each dataframe are consecutive integers.

Expected results:

```
> bg_df1
   cb    type
4   4 bg_long
5   5 bg_long
6   6 bg_long

> bg_df2
   cb    type
9   9 bg_long
10 10 bg_long
```

How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/21421047/559784

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please note that the quality of SO not only relies on the questions and answers but also on the up/downvote scores and the green tick that the original poster can click to accept the best answer. Please contribute to the SO community by following these "rules". Thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry I forgot it, the answer below has been accepted, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not answer your actual question, but get's the job done. Before you subset your data, use `data.table::rleid` to create an index variable.

```
df$idx <- data.table::rleid(df$type)

# or without data.table package
# rle_type <- rle(df$type)
# df$idx <- rep(seq_len(length(rle_type$lengths)), rle_type$lengths)
df
#   cb    type idx
#1   1   short   1
#2   2  g_long   2
#3   3  g_long   2
#4   4 bg_long   3
#5   5 bg_long   3
#6   6 bg_long   3
#7   7  g_long   4
#8   8  g_long   4
#9   9 bg_long   5
#10 10 bg_long   5
```

Now subset and then `split` your data on `idx`.

```
bg_df <- df[df$type == 'bg_long',]
split(bg_df, bg_df$idx)
#$`3`
#  cb    type idx
#4  4 bg_long   3
#5  5 bg_long   3
#6  6 bg_long   3

#$`5`
#   cb    type idx
#9   9 bg_long   5
#10 10 bg_long   5
```

To delete the idx column do

```
lapply(bg_lst, `[<-`, "idx", value = NULL)
```

If you need these two datasets in your global environment, do

```
bg_lst <- setNames(bg_lst, paste0("bg_df", 1:2))
list2env(bg_lst, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: @MagicPants Glad to help. Please consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.